# Splitting an Array- alternative to copyOfRange

Tags: java, arrays

I realise copyOfRange is best here but I also need an alternative way of splitting this array into 2 subarrays:

// MergeSort splits the array into two collections

```
public static void mergeSort1(int[] a) {

    // if the size of the array is greater than 1
    if (a.length > 1) {

        int middle = a.length / 2; // the array is split in half to get a midpoint

        // copy the array into new array called leftArray which goes from 0 the new
        // end-point 'middle'
        int[] leftArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, middle);
        // start of rightArray which finishes at the 'middle'
        int[] rightArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, middle, a.length);

        // call MergeSort to recursively sort both halves
        mergeSort1(leftArray);
        mergeSort1(rightArray);

        // now merge the sorted halves into sorted array
        merge(a, leftArray, rightArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this method to split your array as a list if you are interested `Arrays.asList(array).subList(x, y)`
but for array copyOfRange is a good approach

Comment: Thanks Navid, can you please show me exactly how I would do this as I am now to this and still learning. I appreciate your help.

Comment: sure! make a new function and pass a List<Integer> as its argument instead of array of int and then:
`List<Integer> leftArray = Arrays.asList(array).sublist(0, middle)`
do the same for rightArray and pass them to your new function.